# How to hide all divs with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering how I can hide all divs on the page only using JavaScript, I cannot use jQuery. Is there a way to do this without using the arrays that comes with `document.getElementByTag`? Or if there is not, could you show me how to hide all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) to get a list of all `div` elements, and then set their CSS [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display) property to `none`:

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.display = 'none';        
}
```

```html
<div>sads</div>
<div>sads</div>
<span>not a div</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `document.getElementsByTagName`, and then use a for loop to process all of the elements:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to put out a totally different solution here.

You could set a CSS class to your body, like this

```
body.hideDivs DIV {
    display: none;
}

document.body.className = "hideDivs";
```

But this would hide everything inside those divs also, which might not be what you are going for here.